# How to get data from database ( github )

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, github

This is what I have written for hwid authentication:

```
try:
    current_machine_id = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')

[1].strip()
        r = requests.get('https://github.com/reactxsw/hwiddump/blob/main/hwid.txt')
    
except:
    print('Error : Internet connection')
    b = input('')
    time.sleep(2)

def Authenticator():
    if not current_machine_id in r.text:
        print('Error : HWID not in database')
        print(f'Invalid HWID :' + current_machine_id)
        a = input('')
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()
    else:
        print("Permission granted !")
        return True

Authenticator()
```

This takes the hwid which is stored in github. I wanted to have a username for each and every hwid.
So I have to do something like `00000000-0000-0000-0000-00D86152166F = REACT` in the.txt I want to make a code which checks for hwid and take the name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do a GET request on raw text URL.

Below is the revised code:

```py
try:
    current_machine_id = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')

[1].strip()
        r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactxsw/hwiddump/main/hwid.txt')
        uuids = r.text.strip().split("\n")
        users = {}
        for i in uuids:
            users[i.split("=")[0].strip()] = i.split("=")[1].strip()

except:
    print('Error : Internet connection')
    b = input('')
    time.sleep(2)

def Authenticator():
    if not current_machine_id in uuids:
        print('Error : HWID not in database')
        print(f'Invalid HWID :' + current_machine_id)
        a = input('')
        time.sleep(5)
        exit()
    else:
        print(f'Hello {users[current_machine_id]}')
        print("Permission granted !")
        return True

Authenticator()
```

Comment: but this is taking all the valuable which is behind the " = " right ? what i want to do is that take the valuable which have been assigned to their hwid which is on the right

Comment: when i change [0] to [1] it is giving output as [React , borabot , p.por]

Comment: yeah then change to [1]

Comment: yea but the point is that let say my hwid is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-00D86152166F right ? i want to get the name of the user which is REACT not all of the name

Comment: i have edited my answer, check if thats what you want

Comment: it give me this after i run it Login as {'00000000-0000-0000-0000-00D86152166F': 'REACT', 'C53B7B73-E899-E811-A4C3-C8D9D2AF10CD': 'borabot', '45323442-3939-3632-3731-3831FFFFFFFF': 'p.por'}

Comment: https://hastebin.com/puxuxeluqi.py << this is the full code. in the def menu(): i want to display the username according to their hwid

Comment: Have you check it yet ?